# QTcpSocket not emit any error or connected signals

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, signals, qtcpsocket

I have a small project which send some data over network using `QTcpSocket`. The server works fine but the client(**[code here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ifIdidcU5fV1Jwam9NMzdJdG8/view?pli=1)**) seems does nothing. If I set breakpoint at `tcpSocket.connectToHost("127.0.0.1",port);`  it does jump in, but not any slots I defined.

I can't figure out what's wrong. I think the environment is ok because I can build 2 working examples from [Qt GUI Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160)

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Hey, someone voted down please tell me why, so at least I don't have the same mistake?

Comment: The minimum case to reproduce the problem must be a part of the question. Your question has been likely downvoted as a link-only question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a [`QApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) instance and thus no event loop which does all the event / signal&slot handling.

So you at least need a [`QCoreApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html) instance like this in main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Client client;
    client.connectToServer();

    return a.exec();
}
```